# SQL Server - Diff result from a simple stupid query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do these simple queries return different results ? Only diff is `@val`.

Query #1:

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR
BEGIN
    SET @val = '0320'

    SELECT 1
    WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(@val, 3, 2) AS INT) + 2000 < YEAR(GETDATE())
END
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING('0320', 3, 2) AS INT) + 2000 < YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: because `NVARCHAR` without length = `NVARCHAR(1)`

Comment: Because you are only casting `@val` as `NVARCHAR (1)`, meaning the only thing it is storing in its value is `'0'`.  The bottom query has the full string.

Comment: damn! now I realized.. thanks for helping the stupid people on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you haven't declared the size of the `NVARCHAR` variable, so in the first example the content of the `@val` is '0', not '0320'.

To fix this, use `DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(10)`.

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
  SET @val = '0320'
  SELECT 1
  WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(@val, 3, 2) AS INT) + 2000 < YEAR(GETDATE())
END
```